# After google sign it not disappearing signin button

Tags: google-signin, angular7

when I Google SignIn after sign in it not disappearing signIn button and also not displaying logout button. but when I press any key then it displaying the logout button and disappearing sign in button.

```
 public googleInit() {
  gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: this.clienttId,
      cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    scope: this.scope
  });
  this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
});
}
public attachSignin(element) {

console.log(this.auth2);

this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
  (googleUser) => {

    this.isLoggedOuts = false;
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    this.googleData.accessToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token;
    this.googleData.email = profile.getEmail();
    this.googleData.name = profile.getName();
    this.googleData.imageurl = profile.getImageUrl();
    this.googleData.id = profile.getId();
    this.googleData.provider = 'google';
    // this.ngOnInit();
  }, (error) => {
    //  alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
  });

}
```

Html code

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedOuts">
  <button class="btn btn-danger mx-auto" id="googleBtn" 
   (click)="attachSignin('googleBtn')">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i><span class="ml-2">Sign in with 
    Google</span>
  </button>

</div>

<br/>

<div *ngIf="!isLoggedOut">
<p>sdfd</p>
<div id="googleBt"></div>
    <button class="btn mx-2" (click)="signOutForGoogle()">Logout</button>
  </div> 

     </div> 

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

I added this script in index.html. file.

so initial isLoggedOuts is true and after login it becoming false.

Please help

Comment: You have both `isLoggedOuts` (with a "s") and `isLoggedOut` (without an "s"). Details matter?

Comment: after changes isLoggOut is not working. main problem is like after getting google data we redirecting to different route. and it going to different route but it also displaying siginin button. and when i press any keyboard key then it disappearing signIn button.